# Get slide layout names for each slide in rpptx object

Tags: r, officer

I want to be able to pass an `rpptx` object into a function that outputs a character vector of slide layout names for each slide in the object.

For example, using a fictitious `get_slide_layouts()` function:

```r
pres <- officer::read_pptx()

pres <- officer::add_slide(pres, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
pres <- officer::add_slide(pres, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")

get_slide_layouts(pres)
```

I would be looking for the output:

```r
c("Title and Content", "Title and Content")
```

`slide_summary()` doesn't seem to give me what I'm looking for. How can I extract the layout names for each slide in the `rpptx` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is an easier way or a convenience function for this task. But one option would be to do:

Note: Basically the approach gets the names by matching filenames from the layouts metadata with the ones from the slide metadata.

```r
pres <- officer::read_pptx()

pres <- officer::add_slide(pres, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
pres <- officer::add_slide(pres, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")

get_slide_layouts <- function(x) {
  layouts <- x$slideLayouts$get_metadata()  
  slides <- x$slide$get_metadata()
  
  layouts[match(basename(slides$layout_file), layouts$filename), "name"]
}

get_slide_layouts(pres)
#> [1] "Title and Content" "Title and Content"
```